# Storyboard elements moves on their own

Tags: xcode, storyboard

Over the past few months, precisely over the past Xcode updates (currently in Xcode 14.2) I have found that when I would reload the storyboard file of my Swift project (a project of about a dozen ViewController) all the elements would show up shifted or resized by a few pixels. There is a known solution for this issue? Searching around I could not find anything.

Thanks in advance.